# Building couchdb with minimal dependencies

Tags: testing, ubuntu, erlang, installation, couchdb

I want to play around and check out Apache's couchdb as a possible back-end for a web-app that I am designing.  Therefore I want to have an instance of couchdb, but also to be able to throw it away when the testing is done.  The development computer is an Ubuntu laptop (not server).  The problems are:

1. The Ubuntu repository has couchdb 1.0, but the couchdb website strongly recommends to install 1.1, built from source.
2. I have Erlang built and installed from source, because the Erlang distro from the repository is defective.  I don't see the point in installing another Erlang aside it.
3. couchdb has **a lot** of dependencies, including a whole bunch of perl libs, that I really don't need, and prefer to throw away when I'm done.

So I am looking for a way to either:

1. Install couchdb 1.1 as a package that can be easily uninstalled, **or**
2. Build couchdb from source, with as few as possible installed dependencies, so when I'm done I can just delete it.  Preferably, do this without building another Erlang distro, but configuring it to use the existing one.

Is any of these possible, and how?  Thanks in advance.

Btw, I am aware of the build-couchdb project, but from what I read, it requires installing all the build dependencies in advance, which is undesirable, because it will leave a whole bunch of dangling packages in my system, without being a dependency of a couchdb package.  It also fetches a copy of Erlang, which is redundant for me.

(Dear moderators: This questions combines issues that relate not only to programming, but also to server administration, Unix software, and, particularly, Ubuntu Linux issues.  Therefore, it might be suitable for a few other stack exchange sites.  I recon it is most likely to be answered here, since this kind of hackery is often done by programmers.  However, if I am wrong, feel free to migrate it, and I apologies in advance for your troubles.)

Answer (score 0):

You could install CouchDB into a chroot jail

> A chroot is a way of isolating applications from the rest of your computer, by putting them in a jail. This is particularly useful if you are testing an application which could potentially alter important system files

From the [Ubuntu instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BasicChroot) on creating a chroot jail

Another option, assuming your laptop has the appropriate hardware virtualization support, is to use KVM.

The KVM option might be more helpful in the long run as you could move the VM's disk image onto a server.